# Will i be able to generate electricity in the following case?

Tags: motor

The motor shown is an alternating current, single-phase induction motor of the permanent split capacitor (PSC) type. I i power the electromagnet part with an AC supply of 12V to generate a magnetic field, and then rotated faster than its synchronous speed will the motor then generate electricity with power 106 watt as stated on the label of the motor in the figure.

[image: Specifications of the motor]

In case 12V is insufficient then how can i find the volt of the current to be supplied to the motor in order to generate the sufficient electromagnetism.

Comment: I doubt that that one in the picture will work at all.

Comment: `generate electricity with power 106 watt as stated on the label`  ... the label does not say anything about generating electricity

Comment: Not likely.  As its rated current is 1A you may get somewhere around 12V 1A or 12W, but it'll be an interesting experiment.

Comment: Read the comments to this question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/514245/152903

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading an Asynchronous Generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430323/loading-an-asynchronous-generator)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply 12VAC to the windings, it will be able to produce 12VAC. The amount of current that it CAN produce, 1A, is based on what the windings can handle safely, so you can possibly get 1A at 12VAC, or 12VA before the windings begin to be damaged.